# SQLAlchemy generating incorrect SQL when using json_to_recordset in query with joins

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to utilize SQLAlchemy to generate a sql query in which a json column needs to be explanded using json_to_recordset and the main table also needs to join to another table. The code is as follows:

```
conditions= func.json_to_recordset(History.json_column) \
            .table_valued(
                column("condition", VARCHAR),
                column("price", VARCHAR),
                column("is_checked", Boolean))\
            .render_derived(with_types=True)
select(
       History.id,
       Site.name,
       conditions.c.condition
      ) \
      .join(Site,Site.id==History.site_id)\
      .filter(conditions!=None)
```

This generates the sql as:

```
SELECT history.id, site.name, anon_1.condition 
FROM json_to_recordset(history.conditions) AS anon_1(condition VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, is_checked BOOLEAN), history JOIN site ON site.id = history.site_id
```

This is incorrect since the json_to_recordset clause in FROM should come after the main table and its join. The SQL generated is correct if the join is not present. How can I correct this?

Comment: Use a native query. It would be easier and much cleaner.